# How to create project setting for Eclipse IDE of a Play Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I am using Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) and Play framework 2.4. I created a Java project using the template id `play-java`. Then I created Eclipse settings for the project using the command `eclipse` at `activator` console. Somehow, the `.project` file got changed and now Eclipse recognizes Java project as Scala project. This means I get no Java help from Eclipse. This is the content of the `.project` file in the root project folder:

```
<projectDescription>
  <name>YMLPushNotificationService</name>
  <buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder</name>
    </buildCommand>
  </buildSpec>
  <natures>
    <nature>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
  </natures>
  <linkedResources> </linkedResources>
</projectDescription>
```

If I manually edit the file and replace the line

`<name>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder</name>`

with

`<name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>`

and run the `eclipse` command from `activator` console, the file gets overwritten to its previous state. How do I make eclipse recognize the project as Java project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `project/plugins.sbt` you need a line with:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

and in your `build.sbt` the following lines:

```
import com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.EclipsePlugin.EclipseKeys

EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java           // Java project. Don't expect Scala IDE
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)  // Use .class files instead of generated .scala files for views and routes
```

Comment: Is this a new feature of Play 2.4? The default type of the project is Scala without adding these lines to `build.sbt` which wasn't the case with earlier versions of Play.

Comment: The settings definitely changed from 2.3 to 2.4: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE#Eclipse